# Is calling the api in a report template 'bad form'?

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

Just a small question - but I've been asked to add 'Address Location Type' as a column in a report. At least as of our civiCRM version (4.7.13) the address seems to me to only contain the location type ID - which doesn't make much sense to users.

I wasn't able to readily find a pseudoconstant function available to handle location type id -> location type name like there are for things like State/Province and Membership Type... so I have it working with the api as below:

```
if (array_key_exists('civicrm_address_location_type_id', $row)) {
        if ($value = $row['civicrm_address_location_type_id']) {
          $rows[$rowNum]['civicrm_address_location_type_id'] = civicrm_api3('LocationType', 'Getvalue', array('id' => $value, 'return' => 'name'));
        }
        $entryFound = TRUE;
      }
```

My question is out of curiosity because I haven't run across an api call in alterDisplay like this (maybe it exists and it's fine) but... is there a better way to do this / is it bad form to get at the location type name this way?

**EDIT:** Here is what i've ended up with (working) based on Coleman's answer below:

```
        //Inside alterDisplay but outside foreach($rows) loop...

$results = civicrm_api3('LocationType', 'get', array('sequential' => 1, 'return' => array("name")));
$locationTypes = array();
  foreach ($results['values'] as $item) {
    $locationTypes[$item['id']]=$item['name'];
  };

        //now for each row it's just...

if (array_key_exists('civicrm_address_location_type_id', $row)) {
  if ($value = $row['civicrm_address_location_type_id']) {
    $rows[$rowNum]['civicrm_address_location_type_id'] = $locationTypes[$value];
  }
  $entryFound = TRUE;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Even better version without 'sequential' or the foreach loop based on Coleman's comment below.

```
            //Inside alterDisplay but outside foreach($rows) loop...

    $results = civicrm_api3('LocationType', 'get', array('return' => array("name")));

            //now for each row...

    if (array_key_exists('civicrm_address_location_type_id', $row)) {
      if ($value = $row['civicrm_address_location_type_id']) {
        $rows[$rowNum]['civicrm_address_location_type_id'] = $results['values'][$value]['name'];
      }
      $entryFound = TRUE;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will result in one api call per row, which can add up to a lot of queries on the db.

A lighter-weight solution would be do do a single api call before the loop to look up all location types and store them in a local variable, then you can use `array_search` or similar for each row to get the proper value.

Comment: That makes lots of sense - thanks! I couldn't grok getting array_search exactly working, but i've edited my question with some working code with just one api call based on this answer, in case someone else finds that useful.

Comment: That looks good. One optimization: If you take out the `sequential=1` from your api call then they will already be indexed by id and you won't need the `foreach ($results['values']` loop.

Comment: Oops looks like I am guilty of not rtfm again for basic api parameters before I tried things out and made it harder on myself :). Thank you for the kind help! I have added a further edit with a third (better) version.